# save .msg format file with exchange web services managed API

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, email, msg

I'm trying to use Exchange Web Services Managed API 1.1 to connect to Exchange and then find out if an email has been sent or received and save a copy of the .msg file to a folder on the disk.

So far, I have the following code

```
Dim service As New Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1)

service.AutodiscoverUrl("name@example.com")
service.UseDefaultCredentials = True
Dim ver = service.RequestedServerVersion

Dim inbox As Folder = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox)
Console.Out.WriteLine(inbox.UnreadCount.ToString())

Dim sentItems As Folder = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.SentItems)
Console.Out.WriteLine(sentItems.TotalCount.ToString())
```

What I want is to fire an event which saves the email (in .msg format) to the file system. But I can't seem to find any way to do this with the EWS Managed API, I would settle for a function to call to see if new messages exist since last call or similar without preforming searches all the time. I would rather not implement this as an outlook plugin because we need it to work seamlessly with the web version as well as the full client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any direct way to do with within the framework so I used Redemption and the following code to resolve it:

```
Dim redSess As Redemption.RDOSession = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Dim savedMsg = redSess.GetMessageFromMsgFile("c:\test_ews_m_API2.msg", True)
savedMsg.Import("c:\test_ews_m_API.eml", 1024)
savedMsg.Save()
```